# xmlhttprequest and putting content to iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, xmlhttprequest

i got 2 websites both under my control and on the same server. a.com displays b.com in iframe and i am trying to implement http header authentication. Right now what i am doing is making a xmlhttprequest with required headers from a.com to b.com and putting the response to an iframe like this

document.getElementById("frame").contentDocument.write(h.responseText);

when i do it like this window.location.href value at the response displays a.com instead of b.com, i am guessing it is because when contentDocument.write writes the response it is written to a.com and not in a proper iframe container... Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong and how i can fix it...

Edit: Here is full code incase anyone needs it

```
var h=new XMLHttpRequest();
h.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(h.readyState==4&&h.status==200){
        var e=document.createElement('iframe');
        e.id="frame";
        e.src="about:blank";    
        document.body.appendChild(e);
        var doc=document.getElementById("frame").contentDocument || document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document;                        
        doc.write(h.responseText);
    }
}
h.open('POST',"request_url_here",true);h.setRequestHeader('custom_header','custom_data');h.send();
```

Comment: This is a bit more complex of an issue that can just be explained in a couple of sentences without a [mcve] and more code specific problem statements. You may also want to look into using postMessage API

Comment: I added code i am using to question, requested page just contains alert(window.location.href); to test... I am trying to send a req with custom headers from a.com to b.com and add response to an iframe, normally when i open b.com window.location.href equals to b.com, with the code i am using it equals to a.com ... It is like the when i put the response content to iframe it becomes a child element of a.com's dom tree instead of iframe containers dom tree...

I dont think i can use postMessage api, i am passing a cached html file by htaccess rules that is why i am trying to use http headers...